# C# UWP app COM error: 80040154 Class not registered

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, com, windows-10

I have an UWP application that I would like to interface with another program (Wirecast). The approach suggested by Wirecast is to call the following code:

```
    Type objClassType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Wirecast.Application");
    _Wirecast = Activator.CreateInstance(objClassType);
```

When I call this code from UWP app I get the following error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Creating an instance of
>   the COM component with CLSID {A416C15B-A073-4994-8DB5-87527A41B2FA}
>   using CoCreateInstanceFromApp failed due to the following error:
>   80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154
>   (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I checked the CLSID and it appears correctly in the Registry Editor. I tried compiling for x64 and x86 configurations with the same results.

When I try compiling this example in WPF project **it works as expected**.

Is there any way to use this COM object with an UWP app?

Comment: You can't, UWP demands that all components are included in the appx package.  IDispatch is not supported.  Unless they can provide you with a UWP compatible api, you must create a normal desktop app instead.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this won't work as UWP runs in a sandbox and it cannot communicate with COM. If you want such functionality, you would have to create a local service via which would your UWP app communicate with the program or a Brokered Windows Runtime Component which has no limitations but will prevent your app from being published to Microsoft Store.

Comment: [Nitpicking details :-)]: UWP can use COM just fine, but there are two complications. First, WACK limits the CLSIDs you can access by forcing you to use `CoCreateInstanceFromApp`. Second, the ACLs on the keys you need to access (or other objects needed) might not grant access to app containers. But there is nothing technically stopping out-of-proc COM from working.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Can you explain the technology more?

Comment: Which bit? COM is pretty standard Windows technology you can read about on Wikipedia or in many books.

Comment: Sorry for the necro @PeterTorr-MSFT, but I'm interested in the parts that allows packaged Win32 clients to activate classes registered from an unpackaged Win32 server - just plain CoRegisterClassObject on the server side will make packaged Win32 clients still fail activation with REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG.